# How to hide Box in Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics

I might be doing something stupid, but I can't see what it is. This simple example shows that I'm trying to hide the Box, but failing. (I tried it just once, in different positions, too.) The code is a little weird, so that might be the problem...

```
splot1 = SphericalPlot3D[
   Cos[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 80];

aGraphicsComplex = splot1[[1]];

Graphics3D[{Boxed -> False, 
  Lighting -> {{"Point", RGBColor[1, .9, .9], {2, 2, 4}}}, 
  Boxed -> False,
  aGraphicsComplex /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, objs__] :> 
    GraphicsComplex[
     With[{r = 4 Sin[11 (ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] + #[[3]] )]},
        {r, r, 2} #] & /@ pts, objs]}]
```

[image: the box that won't go away]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work as you need to feed the option `Boxed -> False` to `Graphics3D` and option should be given after the argument in a function.

```
splot1 = SphericalPlot3D[
Cos[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
PlotPoints -> 80];
aGraphicsComplex = splot1[[1]];
Graphics3D[{Lighting -> {{"Point", RGBColor[1, .9, .9], {2, 2, 4}}}, 
aGraphicsComplex /. 
GraphicsComplex[pts_, objs__] :> 
GraphicsComplex[
 With[{r = 4 Sin[11 (ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] + #[[3]])]}, {r, r, 
      2} #] & /@ pts, objs]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Right! Thanks for correcting..

Comment: @PlatoManiac Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

`Boxed -> False` is an *option* of `Graphics3D` so it must come *after* the first argument, not as part of it in a list.

```
Graphics3D[{...}, Boxed -> False]
```

This is valid for the other options too, just move them to the end.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I must have thought that both Mesh and Box options would make their way through from SphericalPlot3D to Graphics3D...

Comment: @cormullion They won't because you are specifically picking out the graphics objects only without any options when you do `splot1[[1]]`